# How to prevent mapview from being deallocated?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, segue

I'm trying to find a way to preserve the region and the zoom of a mapview when i switch between 2 view controllers.

What's happening now is that every time i come back from the child view controller the mapview reinitializes itself and so userTrackingMode and userLocation too.

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initLocationManager()
  }
}

extension MainViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {

  func initLocationManager() {  
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.Follow, animated: true)
  }

  func stopLocationServices() {
    mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.None, animated: true)
  }

  func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    if mapViewRegionDidChangeFromUserInteraction() {
      mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.None, animated: false)
    }
  }

func centerMapToUser() {
  mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.Follow, animated: true)
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
  guard annotation is MapAnnotation else {
    return nil
  }

  return MapAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotation.description)
  }
}
```

Is there a specific segue that prevents the deallocation of the parent view or maybe i was thinking about storing the desired region.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

you can try a lazy implementation like this.

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) MapView *mapView;

- (MapView *)mapView
{
    if (!_mapView) {
        _mapView = [MapView new];
    }
    return _mapView;
}
```

Or maybe, only changing the property to strong from weak could solve your issue. 
If it doesn't, please provide more info about your code.